# How do I blacklist a command in Linux?

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, command-line

I would like to blacklist a command in Linux or add it to sudo to avoid typing it by accident.

I was trying to fix my RVM and for some reason typed:

`rvm reset`

And lost all my gemsets.

I would like to change this behavior to `sudo rvm reset` and perhaps add a comment that says what this command will do.

Comment: `chmod 700 \`which rvm\``

Answer (score 3):

I would wrap a shell function around rvm:

```
rvm () {
    case $1 in
        reset)
            echo "danger Will Robinson" >&2
            echo "run 'command rvm reset' if you really want it" >&2
            ;;
        *) command rvm "$@" ;;
    esac
}
```

Comment: This is a good suggestion because it only affects interactively running commands in the terminal. It won't unexpectedly affect any tools, scripts, services for you or other users.

Comment: Thanks @glenn-jackman. How do I implement this? In the rvm binaries or how?

Comment: Just add that to your ~/.bashrc and then `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I added this to `.bashrc` but it looks like it's making rvm unstable or act in a weird way. "rvm is not a function selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work". The solution to this behavior is to set the terminal to run as login shell. Which I had already. Removing above code will set things back to normal. Perhaps there is a way to `sudo` the command `rvm reset` somehow. I find this could be helpful to sudo something like `rm -rf` in a home directory.

Answer (score 1):

```
chown root `which rvm` 
chmod 0700 `which rvm`
```

to restrict gemset delete command use something like this:

```
chown -R root `rvm gemdir`
sudo chmod -R 0755 `rvm gemdir`
```

even chmod maybe unnecessary. But you'll need sudo for new gemset installations.

Comment: But this will enable sudo for every rvm command right? Not sure if I would ever need to sudo things as simple as `rvm gemset list`. More interested on the `delete` side of things that can mess up your env and not on read. It would be like `sudo ls` something in `~`.

Comment: yes, since this commands changes ownership and rwx rights of the rvm file it will require root privileges for all invocations of that command.

Comment: there is another way... if your gemsets are files change their ownership to root and restrict write to others group. So rvm won't have rights to delete them. But this will require chown and chmod for any new gemset.